# Making tables and update calculated values

Tags: functions, function-construction, list-manipulation, output-formatting

I'm trying to make tables like in the image to calculate max and min of the expressions.
Whenever I change the max and min of `a` and `b` in the upper table then the `MixEx`and `MaxEx` are updated automatically.

How can I do that in Mathematica?
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few customizations for the `IntervalSlider` and `InputField` controls:

```
ClearAll[thumb, intSlider, inpField]
thumb = Graphics[{#, Text[Style["▲", #, 16], Offset[{0, -20}, {0, 0}]], 
     Text[Style[#2, 12], Offset[{0, -35}, {0, 0}]]}, ImageSize -> 20] &;

intSlider[Dynamic[{x_, y_}], range_, opts___ : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 IntervalSlider[Dynamic[{x, y}], range, Method -> "Stop", 
  Appearance -> {"ThumbAppearance" -> {thumb[Red, Dynamic[x]], None, 
      thumb[Blue, Dynamic[y]]}}, ImageSize -> {400, 50}, opts]

inpField = InputField[#, Appearance -> "Frameless", FieldSize -> 5, 
    Alignment -> Center] &;
```

Given a list of input functions, we only need the functions `Interval` and `MinMax` to find the extrema of the input expressions:

```
ClearAll[functions, minMax]
functions = {# + #2 &, -# &, # + 2 #2 &, -#2 &, #- #2&, #2 - #&, 1/(2 # - #2) &};
minMax[f_][x_, y_] := MinMax@f[Interval@x, Interval@y]
```

The `IntervalSlider`s and `InputField`s are used to specify the input.

```
DynamicModule[{a = {20, 50}, b = {35, 75}}, Dynamic @ 
    Grid[{{Grid[{{Labeled[intSlider[Dynamic@{a[[1]], a[[2]]}, {0, 100, 1}], 
         Style["a", 16], Left], SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft},
      {Labeled[intSlider[Dynamic@{b[[1]], b[[2]]}, {0, 100, 1}], 
         Style["b", 16], Left], SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft}}, 
      Dividers -> All, ItemSize -> 10]}, 
   {Grid[{{"a", SpanFromLeft, "b", SpanFromLeft} /. s_String :>
          Item[s, Background -> LightGray], 
       Item[#, Background -> LightBlue] & /@ {"min", "max", "min", "max"},
       Item[#, Background -> LightYellow] & /@ 
        {inpField[Dynamic[a[[1]]]], inpField[Dynamic[a[[2]]]], 
         inpField[Dynamic[b[[1]]]], inpField[Dynamic[b[[2]]]]}}, 
      Frame -> {All, All}, ColumnsEqual -> True, ItemSize -> 10, Alignment -> Center]},
    {Dynamic@ Grid[{{"expr", SpanFromLeft, "min (expr)", "max (expr)"} /. 
          s_String :> Item[s, Background -> LightMagenta],
       ## & @@ Table[{foo["a", "b"], SpanFromLeft, ##& @@ minMax[foo][a, b]}, 
          {foo, functions}]}, 
      Dividers -> All, ColumnsEqual -> True, ItemSize -> 10, Alignment -> Center]}}]]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

**Note:** You can also define `functions` as

```
functions = Function[{x, y}, #] & /@
   {x + y, -x, x + 2 y, -y, x - y, y - x, 1/(2 x - y)}
```

**Update:** Dealing with cases where some input expression are lists, as in,for example,

```
expList = {x + y, 2 x, {x + y, 2 x}, -x, x + 2 y, -y, x - y, y - x,  1/(2 x - y)}
```

We need to modify `minMax` to handle lists:

```
ClearAll[minMax, functions]

minMax[f_][x_, y_] := MinMax@f[Interval@x, Interval@y]

minMax[f_List][x_, y_] := MinMax@Transpose[minMax[#][x, y] & /@ f]
```

Second, we need to transform the input list to a list of functions:

```
functions = Block[{bar}, 
  Map[bar, expList, 1] /. bar[l_List] :> bar /@ l /. bar -> (Function[{x, y}, #] &)]
```

Finally, we need to change the first argument of `Table` in the last grid to handle lists in the `functions` list properly.

With these changes (removing  the second grid with input fields):

```
DynamicModule[{a = {20, 50}, b = {35, 75}}, 
 Dynamic@Grid[{{Grid[{{Labeled[intSlider[Dynamic@{a[[1]], a[[2]]}, {0, 100, 1}], 
         Style["a", 16], Left], SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft}, 
    {Labeled[intSlider[Dynamic@{b[[1]], b[[2]]}, {0, 100, 1}], 
         Style["b", 16], Left], SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft}}, 
    Dividers -> All, ItemSize -> 10]},
 {Dynamic@ Grid[{{"expr", SpanFromLeft, "min (expr)", "max (expr)"} /. 
         s_String :> Item[s, Background -> LightMagenta], 
     ## & @@ Table[{If[Head[foo] === List, Through@foo["a", "b"], foo["a", "b"]], 
                    SpanFromLeft, ## & @@ minMax[foo][a, b]}, 
                    {foo, functions}]},
  Dividers -> All, ColumnsEqual -> True, ItemSize -> 10, Alignment -> Center]}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: This's  hard to understand but run pretty fast.

Comment: I think that solved my problem but how can I change if the expr is now {a+b, 2a}? 
I meant it includes 2 expressions and we find min and max accounting both of them.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: I just realized that it doesn't work with `a-b`.

Comment: `a-b` doesn't work. if you set `lower a = 20, lower b =20`, and then move upper b to around 35, the min expression should be negative but it doesn't.

Comment: do you have any idea making expression like `{a+b, 2a}` work now? I tried Nasser solution but it's too slow when I adding more. This code is fast but hard to modify.The table with `a, b` is not necessary.

Comment: The expression only in the form {a+b, 2a} so just this case is okay

Comment: @anhnha, what is the expected output ( `Min[expr]` and `Max[expr]` ) for input `expr = {a+b, 2a}`?

Comment: min and max of the expression is the smaller value and larger value of both expressions. 
`Min[expr] = Min[a+b, 2a]` and `Max[expr] = Max[a+b, 2a]`

Comment: How would you change the first argument of `Table`?

Comment: sorry forgot to add the code piece; done.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use `Minimize` and `Maximize` with constraint.

Need to make sure min is smaller than max, else you'll get unexpected results.

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{a, b},
  Quiet@Grid[{
     {"expression", "Min", "Max"},
     {"a+b", 
      First@Minimize[{a + b, minA < a < maxA && minB < b < maxB}, {a, b}], 
      First@Maximize[{a + b, minA < a < maxA && minB < b < maxB}, {a, b}]},
     {"-a", First@Minimize[{-a, minA < a < maxA}, a], 
      First@Maximize[{-a, minA < a < maxA}, a]},
     {"a+2 b", First@Minimize[{a + 2 b, minA < a < maxA && minB < b < maxB}, {a, b}], 
      First@Maximize[{a + b, minA < a < maxA && minB < b < maxB}, {a,b}]},
     {"-b", First@Minimize[{-b, minB < b < maxB}, b], 
      First@Maximize[{-b, minB < b < maxB}, b]}
     }, Frame -> All
    ]
  ],
 {{minA, 1, "Min of a"}, 0, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{maxA, 3, "Max of a"}, 0, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{minB, 2, "Min of b"}, 0, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{maxB, 6, "Max of b"}, 0, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {minA, minB, maxA, maxB} 
 ]
```

Comment: Thank you. Because actually I have 5 times bigger than this, so can I use IntervalSlider  to make max and min?