# How this foo, ## & @@ work?

Tags: functions, list-manipulation

Can anyone explain the code below? The problem is in this part of the code. What is `foo`, `## & @@`? I have been looking at this code for several hours but have no idea how it works.

```
## & @@ Table[Flatten@{foo["a", "b"], SpanFromLeft, 
            minMax@foo[a, b]}, {foo, functions}]
```

Full code:

```
ClearAll[functions, minMax]
functions = {# + #2 &, -# &, # + 2 #2 &, -#2 &, 1/(2 # - #2) &};
minMax = MinMax@*Interval;
DynamicModule[{a = {20, 50}, b = {35, 75}}, 
 Dynamic@Grid[{{Grid[{{Labeled[
         intSlider[Dynamic@{a[[1]], a[[2]]}, {0, 100, 1}], 
         Style["a", 16], Left], SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, 
        SpanFromLeft}, {Labeled[
         intSlider[Dynamic@{b[[1]], b[[2]]}, {0, 100, 1}], 
         Style["b", 16], Left], SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, 
        SpanFromLeft}}, Dividers -> All, ItemSize -> 10]}, {Dynamic@
      Grid[{{"expr", SpanFromLeft, "min (expr)", "max (expr)"} /. 
         s_String :> Item[s, Background -> LightMagenta], ## & @@ 
         Table[Flatten@{foo["a", "b"], SpanFromLeft, 
            minMax@foo[a, b]}, {foo, functions}]}, Dividers -> All, 
       ColumnsEqual -> True, ItemSize -> 10, Alignment -> Center]}}]]
```

Source: [Making tables and update calculated values](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214520/making-tables-and-update-calculated-values)

Comment: `foo` is just a variable name; `{foo,functions}` tells that this variable must take values from the list `functions`. For example, `numbers = {1,2,3}` followed by `Table[foo + 1, {foo, numbers} ]` returns `{2,3,4}`

Answer (score 8):

Try it:

```
## & @@ {1, 2, 3}
(* Sequence[1, 2, 3] *)
```

`Sequence` is a wrapper for a list that you want expanded into separate function arguments when it appears in an argument list.

I cannot say why the author didn't just do `Sequence @@`.

Comment: `Sequence @@` is a lot more typing.

Comment: Can you explain `minMax = MinMax@*Interval` and `foo` too?  I read that `@*` is a composition but what does `MinMax@*Interval@foo[a, b]` return? From what I read `Interval` should have two variables but this one has only one.

Comment: `Interval[{min,max}]` can accept *one list*.  Although, it can also accept more than one list: `Interval[{min1, max1},{min2, max2}, ... ]`